# Excluding Record Type from Validation Rule

Tags: formula

I'm trying to exclude the following record type from this rule, and I have tried just about everything I can think of, `And(` `If(` `&&`(before and after).  Anyone see any mistakes? `012E00000008cwPIAQ` is the record type I want to exclude from this rule.

`AND( 
ISPICKVAL(Product__r.Product_Status_Code1__c ,"60|Planned Withdrawal, NR")|| 
ISPICKVAL(Product__r.Product_Status_Code1__c , "70|Withdrawal From Sales")|| 
ISPICKVAL(Product__r.Product_Status_Code1__c , "80|End Of Support,EOL")|| 
ISPICKVAL(Product__r.Product_Status_Code1__c , "90|Obsolete/Inactive")) && RecordType.Id != '012E00000008cwPIAQ'`

Another attempt

`IF(
RecordTypeId != '012E00000008cwPIAQ',
ISPICKVAL(Product__r.Product_Status_Code1__c,"60|Planned Withdrawal, NR")||
ISPICKVAL(Product__r.Product_Status_Code1__c,"70|Withdrawal From Sales,")||
ISPICKVAL(Product__r.Product_Status_Code1__c,"80|End Of Support,EOL")||
ISPICKVAL(Product__r.Product_Status_Code1__c,"90|Obsolete/Inactive"),true)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it seems like it should work. I would just use Name instead of Id.

If you are running this validation rule for the record you want to exclude, this should work:

```
AND( 
  Id != "012E00000008cwPIAQ",
  OR(
    ISPICKVAL(Product__r.Product_Status_Code1__c ,"60|Planned Withdrawal, NR"),
    ISPICKVAL(Product__r.Product_Status_Code1__c , "70|Withdrawal From Sales"),
    ISPICKVAL(Product__r.Product_Status_Code1__c , "80|End Of Support,EOL"),
    ISPICKVAL(Product__r.Product_Status_Code1__c , "90|Obsolete/Inactive"))
)
```

If you are excluding a relanshionship field you can just use `RecordType != '012E00000008cwPIAQ'`

Comment: So for some reason it doesn't like it when I use the ID, so I have to use the name.. I've read it's not the best technique but whatever.. it works.

Comment: @EricSSH -- I've also had better luck with names (versus IDs) in validation rules. Not sure why, but you are not alone.